# Spring mongodb get by two params within box throw repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I try to get data from mongoDb throw repository by two parameters which both I would like to be in `box bounds`:

**model**

```
    @Document(collection = "houses")
public class House {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;
/* getters and setters ommited*/ }
```

**Repository**

```
public interface HouseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<House, String> {

    @Query("{'name': {'$regex': '?0','$options' : 'i'}}")
    Set<Hotel> findWithNameContains(String name);

    Set<Hotel> findByLatitudeAndLongitudeWithin(Box bounds);

    Set<Hotel> findByLatitudeAndLongitudeWithin(Circle circle);
}
```

but when I call:

```
     Box bounds = new Box(geoLocation.getLocationCordinates().getNortheastBounds(),geoLocation.getLocationCordinates().getSouthwestBounds());
    houseRep.findByLatitudeAndLongitudeWithin(bounds);
```

I get :

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!
org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:178)
org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameter(Parameters.java:248)
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor.getBindableValue(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:107)
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor$BindableParameterIterator.next(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:150)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ConvertingParameterAccessor$ConvertingIterator.next(ConvertingParameterAccessor.java:176)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.from(MongoQueryCreator.java:240)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.and(MongoQueryCreator.java:133)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.and(MongoQueryCreator.java:58)
org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
```

To say truth, do not where is problem, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The error results from lon/lat being individual properties. Using MongoDB you need to store location data either as array or in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format.

```
loc : [ 37.7577 , -122.4376 ]   //...legacy format
loc : { type : "Point", coordinates : [ 37.7577 , -122.4376 ] }  //...GeoJSON
```

Using Spring Data you have to option to use a `double []` or `Point` for legacy as well as `GeoJsonPoint` for GeoJSON representation (see. [Reference: GeoSpatial Queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.geospatial)). This allows you to use derived query methods like

```
List<Hotel> findByLocationNear(Point point);
GeoResults<Hotel> findByLocationNear(Point point, Distance maxDistance);
List<Hotel> findByLocationWithin(Circle circle);
List<Hotel> findByLocationWithin(Box box);
List<Hotel> findByLocationWithin(Polygon polygon);
```